# Add an Array to Model and Data in Angular 2 with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, model

I get the following error when trying to add a descriptives array to my data and model. 
error TS2322: Type '{ "id": string; "name": string; "competency": string; "descriptives": string[]; "year": string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Competency[]'.
  Type '{ "id": string; "name": string; "competency": string; "descriptives": string[]; "year": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Competency'.
    Types of property 'descriptives' are incompatible.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Descriptive[]'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Descriptive'.
app/app.routes.ts(9,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module './inventory/inventory.component'.

mocksCompetency.ts

```
    import { Competency } from './competency';
    export const COMPETENCY: Competency[] = [
{
    "id": "EngLA001",
    "name": "Oral Language",
    "competency": "The teacher understands the importance of oral language, knows the development processes of oral language and provides the students with varied opportunities to develop listening and speaking skills.",
    "descriptives": ["Something","More"],
    "year": "2014",
}
    ];
```

competency.ts

```
    export class Competency {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    competency: string;
    descriptives: Descriptive[];
    year: string;
    }
    export class Descriptive {
        description: string;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
"descriptives" : ["Something More"]
```

According to your class, `descriptives` should be of type `Descriptive[]`. And `Descriptive` is defined as:

```
export class Descriptive {
     description: string;
}
```

This means that you should really be doing:

```
"descriptives": [{description: "Something More"}]
```

As an aside, you should probably be using `interface` instead of `class` for `Competency` and `Descriptive`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is tremendously helpful!